# Image not found using Angular server on raspberry pi

Tags: html, angular, raspberry-pi3

I've set up my **Raspberry pi** using Angular. Creating a simple website with just the basic `ng serve` command.

The first thing is that I wanted to add my own image. However, every time I try src to my image it is not found:

`<img src="air.JPG">`

If I try then again to run the image standard provided with the Angular `favicon.ico`. Then it does work

`<img src="favicon.ico">`

For some reason one can be found but the other not?

I'm accessing the website externally from my computer. The server is hosted via the command `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
>   or if go from an external ip address:
>   GET http://212.204.xxx.xx:xxxx/air.JPG 404 (Not Found)
>   (left out a few xxxx for privacy :p)

I've already tried moving the image up and down (also into assets). I've tried using the full path of the raspberry. I've tried to give the ip address and path.

Comment: Have you added this image to the two assets sections in the angular.json file? Try copying the favicon.ico line but with your image name.

Comment: I never knew the images had to be added into the assets sections of angular.json file. Currently, I've added the image folder to the assets and all my images work fine now! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All new assets you want to be included that are not in the existing assets folder need to be added to the "assets" section of your **angular.json** file.

Note - there are two assets sections in the file. One for the build and one for running tests.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you :D (and thank you Mathias as well who came with the same solution in the comment section)

Comment: Same person in the comments  :-)

Comment: Maybe I could use some new glasses as well :p